# PostAsJsonAsync does not return response and eventually times out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I have an MVC website that makes an API call using a `HttpClient`. I configured the timeout to be 2 minutes and the API call generally returns within 90 seconds. I can see from application logging that the API completes its execution. If I also call the API method using a tool like Postman or SOAPUI I get a JSON response after 90 seconds.

I cannot get my MVC application to return the response and instead after 2 minutes it will throw an OperationCanceledException which I catch.

```
public async Task<CommonApiResult> PostAsync<T>(string url, TimeSpan timeout, T payload)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = timeout;
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, payload);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsString(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new CommonApiResult<T>
            {
                StatusCode = response.StatusCode,
                Data = stringContent.Deserialize<T>(url)
            };
        }
     }
     return null;
}
```

I never get to the code `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)`.

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong? I have looked at a lot of questions and they all seem to be incorrectly using. Result and not using await like me.

Comment: Are you using `Result` or `Wait` or any other kind of blocking *anywhere further up your call stack?*

Comment: Yes, there is a bit of a chain whereby each method is a async Task. Each time the method is called i always use await. I never use Result.

The only other thing worth point out is that the MVC application has a controller method which uses Task.Run. I do this so i can redirect the user but then do some processing in the background.

Comment: Using `Task.Run` for this kind of "background work" is dangerous. There are [much better options available](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone visit this link in the future.

if it is called via like button click event please check does the button in form tag and has type submit. if yes remove it from the tag